# Procedurally generated texture for Particle with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, procedural-generation

My goal is to create a particle system that involve procedurally generated texture for each particle (vertices), but I find it difficult to create a prototype of such particle system that works under both Canvas and WebGL renderer with three.js

Criteria I am trying to achieve:

1. **Renderer independent** (ParticleCanvasMaterial won't work with WebGL)
2. **Circular texture** (ParticleBasicMaterial does not like canvas texture; unable to make it output a circle shape)
3. **Procedurally generate those texture** (cannot just use loadTexture with prepared circle texture)

Is this currently possible with three.js? Am I missing some features?

```
//create a texture generation function
function simpleTexture() {

    // generate canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    // get context
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // circle texture
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fill();

    // get texture
    texture = new THREE.Texture(
        canvas
    );

    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    return texture;

}

    //then use it like following...

    var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        size: 1,
        map: simpleTexture,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    });

    var system = new THREE.ParticleSystem(particles, material);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about question 1. Use `ParticleCanvasMaterial` for `CanvasRenderer`.

Regarding 2 and 3, you *can* have a procedurally-generated texture with `ParticleBasicMaterial` and `WebGLRenderer`. Here is one with a circular texture and random vertex colors: http://jsfiddle.net/7yDGy/1/

Comment: Thanks, your example looks surprisingly like mine, I must be missing some attributes on the second issue. (oh, before I accept this answer, can I confim this solution will NOT work with CanvasRenderer? Because that's my initial question: **is it possible to do this and still allow fallback to CanvasRenderer, thus 'Renderer independent'**)

Comment: So basically I need some ways to normalize ParticleCanvasMaterial and ParticleBasicMaterial, and choose material type according to renderer, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what you will have to do. Give it a go, and if you have further problems, please post a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not load an image? You can always tweak its attribues on the fly, rahter than shoving whole new blocks of pixels around.

Comment: because my ultimate goal is to create a procedually generated planetary system, so texture (terrain) is very much different from each other. (did not go for sphere geometry due to performance in canvas renderer)